# I would like a way to get individual anchor vars from a url and then apend all links within a specific <div> with the anchor vars

Tags: javascript, url, get, append, anchor

I would like a way to get individual anchor vars from a url and then apend all links within a specific   with the anchor vars.

i.e. Current url for get vars: http://www.bestforbusiness.com#a_aid=affname&a_bid=34837e17

current links in div for replacement: 
`<a href="http://australia.bestforbusiness.com">Australia</a>`

The result whould be:
`<a href="http://australia.bestforbusiness.com#a_aid=affname&a_bid=34837e17">Australia</a>`

I dont mind if it is done with javascript or Jquery just need some help stiching it all together as i am a noob when it comes to javascript.

Hope this is clear enough, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var anchor_vars = document.location.hash;
    $("#target_div a").each(function(idx, item) { // REPLACE target_div with proper id
        $(item).attr('href', $(item).attr('href') + anchor_vars);
    });
});
```

Comment: this solution fits my needs perfectly as it specified the document.location.hash, and thanks to the comment was able to understand how to refeance the specific dom element i.e. #target_div

Answer (score 0):

Using Jquery

```
var customAnchorVars="#a_aid=affname&a_bid=34837e17";
$("div a").each(function()
{
  $(this).attr("href",$(this).attr("href")+customAnchorVars);

})
```